# Class Syntax : React Component Fires the OnChange within Closure

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs, closures

In my `React` code, to create a closure, Im calling "onChange"

```
class CityInput extends React.Component {
    constructor( props ){
        super( props );
        this.state = {
            city : "",
            country : ""
        };
        this.setChangeType = this.setChangeType( this );
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind( this );
    }

    setChangeType( cityOrCountry ){
        return this.onChange;
    }

    onChange( e ){
        console.log( "e.target.value", e.target.value );
        this.setState({
            [ cityOrCountry ] : e.target.value
        })
    }
    ...
    render(){
        return(
            <form onSubmit = { this.onEnter }>
                <label>
                    City : 
                    <input type = "text"
                             name = "cityName"
                             placeholder = "london"
                             value = { this.state.city }
        // the following line executes 'setChangeType' on render,
        // which is suppose to return 'onChange' func, ready to be
        // executed once the onChange is fired by the user.
        // However, thats not happening right now, the function
        // 'onChange' is also fired by 'setChangeType' & I 
        // get the error : 'e.target is undefined'
                             onChange = { this.setChangeType( "city" )} />
                </label>
             .... // rest of form
            </form>
        );
    }
};
```

For some reason, I dont comprehend, the func 'this.setChangeType("city")' gets fired correctly, however, instead of returning the function 'onChange', onChange is also fired. What am I doing wrong?

I get the console error : "e.target is undefined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is

```
this.setChangeType = this.setChangeType( this );
```

which should be

```
this.setChangeType = this.setChangeType.bind( this );
```

*However*, you can also delete that line completely since it is not necessary for your code to work correctly (you are not using `setChangeType` as a callback).

Otherwise, `this.setChangeType` will have the same value as `this.onChange`, i.e. calling `this.setChangeType('city')` actually calls `this.onChange('city')`.

Comment: would you know why the variable 'cityOrCountry' is not accessible with the 'onChange' function? I would have thought Im creating a closure, which was the whole point of the 'setChangeType' function.

Comment: You can only create a closure by defining a function in the scope where the variable is defined. `return this onChange` doesn't define a function, it returns a reference to an existing one. You could do `return e => this.onChange(e, cityOrCountry);` instead, but then you could also just inline it in the `render` method: `onChange = { e => this.onChange(e, "city" )}`. Both however will create a new function every time the component is rendered, potentially resulting in strange behavior with the input.

Comment: You might be better off creating a new component that takes `cityOrCountry` as a prop and renders the input.

Comment: good point with boths. Thank you very much. The one line about closure makes perfect sense and yes, I should create a new component for input. Thanks yet again.